# Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail. Is GmailApp.search() using up quota? Or what?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I'm getting the above error. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), the daily quota is 50,000 email reads/writes. But my scripts/add-ons aren't doing anything heavy duty, and they're not processing many emails (two scripts processing a few dozen threads every five minutes). So there's no obvious optimization I can see.

Each script/add-on starts by doing a GmailApp.search() for threads to be processed. The number of emails being searched is large (thousands), but the number of emails found is small (10-20). Is it possible that the GmailApp.search() operation is using up quota?

Are there any other likely culprits?

Comment: Can you add details like code used so that we can check the implementation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984486/understanding-gmail-api-quotas and https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#per-method_quota_usage
 may be helpful

Comment: Thanks. I can't really upload the code because the Gmail access lines are mixed up with a load of other stuff. The problem seems to have gone away on its own. Thanks for the links, too.